# How to read DGN using GDAL in VB.Net?

Tags: gdal, vector, vb.net, cad, dgn

Reading a DGN file is a big problem for me. I tried more and more but can't find a way to read a dgn(v8) file by VB.Net. After many search, i found out that GDAL can read and write dgn file, but i 'm not able to use it. 
Can anyone help me to do that ?

Comment: GDAL does not support DGN v.8 so you are out of luck with it http://www.gdal.org/drv_dgn.html.

Answer (score 1):

I am an old school dgn user - to use a .dgn file in any other program other than microstation - it must first be exported as a .dxf

http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions [here](http://vipassanaandenvironmentalinformatics.blogspot.com/2013/03/getting-started-with-c-and-gdal.html).Although the samples are for C#,you can make use them in VB.NET with relative ease.